# cycle through 3 colors then back to original color

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been creating a element on the canvas, on which the user touches / or clicks the circle to change its color

this is where i am at so far.

```
circle.on('touchstart', function() {
       var fill = this.getFill() == '#DDDDDD' ? '#FFC926' : '#FF0000';
        this.setFill(fill);
        layer.draw();
      });
```

the start color is #DDDDDD then when its clicked or touched chages to #FFC926 and then when clicked or touched changes to #FF0000 how can i add 1 more color and then revert back to the original color

what i need to happen is:

Start:  #DDDDDD

touch1: #FFC926

touch2: #FF0000

touch3: #000000

touch4: #DDDDDD (rest it)

Just not sure how i do this with JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement to set the right color.

```
circle.on('touchstart', function() {
   var current = this.getFill();
   var fill = "";
   switch (current) {
      case "#DDDDDD":
         fill = "#FFC926";
         break;
      case "#FFC926":
         fill = "#FF0000";
         break;
      case "#FF0000":
         fill = "#000000";
         break;
      default:
         fill= "#DDDDDD";
   }
   this.setFill(fill);
   layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well there are many method available

One is switch case :- give in answer by @TeeDeJee

a) I will suggest you a array method , because it is easy to maintain and you can add more color option in future to it

```
 var colorArray = new Array('#DDDDDD','#FFC926','#FF0000','#000000'); // add more color in the array

 arrayCounter = 0;               
 circle.on('touchstart', function() {
      if(arrayCounter == colorArray.length){
        arrayCounter = 0;
      }
       var fill = colorArray[arrayCounter++];
        this.setFill(fill);
        layer.draw();
  });
```

b) The second one uses your conditional statement  logic , but in a bit complex way

```
 circle.on('touchstart', function() {
       var  fill = (color == '#DDDDDD')? '#FFC926': (color == '#FFC926' ) ? '#FF0000' : (color == '#000000' ) ? '#DDDDDD' : '#000000';
        this.setFill(fill);
        layer.draw();
  });
```